# Ошибка отправки на сервер

Tags: javascript

Используя базовый код от SolidJS сделал поле ввода и кнопку

Пытаюсь отправить конвертированный в JSON текст  используя fetch на определенный ip адрес на котором запущен сервер.
(мы в локальной сети)

Но в консоль выдает ошибку:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/*ip сервера* net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Я так понимаю он ищет этот ip на локальном хосте, где запущена страница.

Но как сделать так чтобы он отправлял на другой сервер данные?

Comment: Покажи как ты используешь `fetch` "на определенный ip адрес на котором запущен сервер"...

Comment: 146% что забыт протокол. Надо написать `http://` перед IP

Comment: Впрочем на 99% уверен, что следующий вопрос будет про CORS :-)

Comment: Alexey Ten, да ты гений. про cors пока сам почитаю, пока в отчаяние впаду